# How can I apply a python function to a pandas dataframe in Alteryx?

Tags: python, alteryx

I have a read in a workflow successfully but when I try and apply a function to a row of the data and output it as another row I get an error.
The following is my curent code;

```
from ayx import Alteryx
import pandas
data = Alteryx.read("#1")

def get_weekday_occurrences(date_string):
    year_day = datetime.strptime(date_string, '%Y_%m_%d').timetuple().tm_yday
    return math.ceil(year_day / 7)
data['Name'] = data['Name'].apply(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, '%Y_%m_%d'))
data['Name'] = data.apply(lambda row : get_weekday_occurrences(data["Name"]), axis = 1)
```

This code gives me the following error;

```
TypeError: ('strptime() argument 1 must be str, not Series', 'occurred at index 0')
```

What am I doing wring please?

Comment: Make your 2nd `apply` more like your 1st.

Comment: PS, since you're using Alteryx, you really should build a function in their Formula tool. You've got arguably the fastest data wrangling tool there is. Use it.